# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the parsed html of button. Basically, it's inside the datagrid.

When I click on this button it gives me console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
<button onclick="myFunction(javed@gmail.com)">Click</button>
```

Here is the scripting for click event.

```
function myFunction(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Comment: `<button onclick="myFunction('javed@gmail.com')">Click</button>` - the string value `javed@gmail.com` need to be wrapped in `''`

Comment: String values need to be wrapped in quotes.  You forgot to do that.

Comment: The value you're passing into the function needs to be quoted, since it's a string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the email as a string, otherwise, it will be parsed as javascript

```
<button onclick="myFunction('javed@gmail.com')">Click</button>
```

Note, not all parameters need to be strings. Passing a number, function, object,or variable without quotes is valid.

If you do not include quotes, thats what the parser will assume your trying to pass but will fail if the parameter is neither of those.